# Unit-test with external class in header file, which does not have virtual method in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

The test framework I am using is the google test/ google mock.

I am writing C++ class, which I would also like to have unittest to test it. This class is using other class from other library, which does not have virtual methods. I read a lot of thread saying that you cannot(or need a lot of effort) mock a class when it is a concrete class(non-virtual). So saying that I am creating a class A using class B from external library, simplified example as below:

```
a.h
class A
{
public:
  A(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
    : mB(b)
  {
  }
  Start()
  {
    mB->ConnectToServer();
  }
  Stop()
  {
    mB->CloseServer();
  }
private:
  mB;
};

b.h
class B
{
public:
  ConnectToServer();
  CloseServer();
};
```

Ideally, I should create a MockB, pass this MockB into the instantiation of A in the test-fixture. And setup the mock, that the ConnectToServer in MockB should be call once when A.Start() is called.

But I cannot mock B, because B does not have virtual method, that is the issue.

But this is a quite common scenario, that you use some library form external source, which might not consider having interface, right?

Does this mean, when you have above scenario, you cannot do proper unit-test?
Or my understanding of unit-test is wrong?

Thanks in advance to give me some hint.

Comment: One option is to wrap B in another class that implements a more general interface for the service B offers. This decouples your code from a third party library, allows you to easily exchange the implementation if needed and makes testing easier.

Comment: One option is to make the 3rdparty class a template argument, then we can run the test with our mocked class.